# Is a START_STICKY service restarted after application killed itself

Tags: java, android, service

So if I understand right, the difference between [`START_STICKY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) and [`START_NOT_STICKY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY) is that the first will be restarted by the system, in case it kills it.

Does anyone know whether this also happens when I kill my application using `Process.killProcess(Process.myPid())`? Or does the system only restart the service if the service was actually being killed externally, not from within the application process?

Comment: try it and find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not always, you can't depend on START_STICKY for continuing running the service. Better way is to use startForeground for continuing running or if you want to repeat specific task then schedule your service on specific time. Also, manage it when the phone is Restarted as well.

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getBaseContext())
                    .setContentTitle(""); 
                    .setContentText("Your content text");
startForeground(1, builder.build());
```

Comment: Both answers are actually right and helped me, I'm deciding for this as it includes a code snippet in addition to the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the START_STICKY service is restarted after the application is killed by the Android System.

Until and unless you call stopService() method from an app component or stopSelf() from within the service, the service will be restarted if the app is killed.

But you can always make the service run using startForeground() method, in which you will have to show a notification in the status bar for your service. If you create a service using this method, your service will run at the same priority as an active activity. This means that it is highly unlikely that your service will be stopped, and no restart would be required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense, I'm working on a business app where everything has to be fully automatic, without any user interaction (part of the requirements). So to catch eventual problems I restart the app every day and reschedule it using AlarmMonitor. In my case it would actually be wrong if the app restarts itself outside my schedule. But the startForeground is a great idea to make it even more stable.